# unit test this.$onDestroy in angular>1.5 / es6

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

using angular 1.5 / es6, I have the following code that I want to test :

```
    this.$onDestroy = function () {
        this.$interval.cancel(someIntervalTimer);
    };
```

I cant find out how to trigger the destruction of the controller in jasmine unit test in order to test what is happening there.
I tried to $destroy() $scope and $rootScope, also $broadcast('$destroy'), etc but none of these seems to trigger the destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$onDestroy` hook is called by directive/component compiler, as well as other controller hooks.

When controller is tested directly with `$controller` or `$componentController`, hook method is supposed to be called manually:

```
spyOn(controllerInstance.$interval, 'cancel');

expect(controllerInstance.$onDestroy).toBe(jasmine.any(Function));

controllerInstance.$onDestroy();

expect(controllerInstance.$interval.cancel).toBeCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object));
```

Comment: One detail, but the param is a promise returned by $interval.

Comment: That's correct, sure. If it can be provided directly instead of `jasmine.any`, this will be even better.